# AlamoFire does not respect timeout interval

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
class APIClient {
    var user = User()
    let alamoFireManager : Alamofire.Manager?
    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()


    init(){
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4 // seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 4
        self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
    }

    func test(){
        //This does not respect the 4 second time out. Why?
        self.alamoFireManager!.request(.POST, CONSTANTS.APIEndpoint+"/test", parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
                        (req, res, json, error)  in
                        if let json = self.handleAPIResponse(req, res: res, json_data: json, error: error){
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the `test` function and print the `self.alamoFireManager!.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest`

Comment: Are you assuming that the first time you call the method test(), it should have a 4 second delay?

Comment: The delay is for the http request not for the complete test method. For example the timeout dose not apply to your handleAPIResponse call.

Comment: What is the use of 'center' object you created?

Answer (score 37):

Are you sure that the 4 seconds timeout is not enforced? I have created an experiment:

```
    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    var alamoFireManager : Alamofire.Manager?

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 4
    self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)

    self.alamoFireManager!.request(.POST, "http://oznet.go.ro/iDorMobile/ConfigServer/api.php/timeout/2", parameters: nil).responseJSON {
        (req, res, json, error)  in
        println("First json \(json)")
        println("First error \(error)")
    }

    self.alamoFireManager!.request(.POST, "http://oznet.go.ro/iDorMobile/ConfigServer/api.php/timeout/6", parameters: nil).responseJSON {
        (req, res, json, error)  in
        println("Second \(json)")
        println("Second \(error)")
    }
```

and the console output i got:

```
First json Optional({
    name = timeoutTest;
    value = 2;
})
First error nil
Second nil
Second Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7f91dc8223e0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://oznet.go.ro/iDorMobile/ConfigServer/api.php/timeout/6, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://oznet.go.ro/iDorMobile/ConfigServer/api.php/timeout/6})
```

The URLs from my example are currently down, i will try to put them back online. *You can use the urls from the example to test. By setting a different number at the end you can modify the timeout (in seconds).*

I have used the cocoapods last version of Alamofire.

Comment: Swift 3 / April 2017: should be `Alamofire.SessionManager`, and `URLSessionConfiguration.default`

Answer (score 9):

You need create a global variable for the request manager:

```
var alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
```

And after configure the custom parameters:

```
 let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 4
    self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's the Swift 3.0 / Alamofire 4.0 code to get an alamofireManager that has a 5 second timeout:

```
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5 // seconds

    let alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: In case of Alamofire 4.0 Alamofire.Manager has been changed to Alamofire.SessionManager as indicated by @Jamie

Answer (score 6):

I guess this one works for you, note that you have to declare instance of **Alamofire.Manager** outside the function, please see below code

```
//Declare it out side the function
var alamoFireManager : Alamofire.Manager!

func callUrl() {
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10800 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10800 // seconds

    alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)

    alamoFireManager.request(.POST, url, parameters: dir as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON, headers: [ "Content-Type": "application/json"])
        .responseJSON { response in
    }
}
```

hope this helps you

Comment: i can confirm that this will not work if the instance of alamofire manager is declared inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

```
 init(){
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 4
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4
    self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
    self.alamoFireManager!.request(.POST, CONSTANTS.APIEndpoint+"/test", parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
                    (req, res, json, error)  in
                    if let json = self.handleAPIResponse(req, res: res, json_data: json, error: error){
                    }
                }
}
```

Use `self.alamoFireManager!.request` in the same init function , timeout delay is only for the request not for the whole function. may be it can help.

Answer (score 1):

I got NSURLErrorDomain when I used above method .
This is my code (swift 3.2/Alamofire 4.4)

```
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4

    manager.request(.POST, CONSTANTS.APIEndpoint+"/test", parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
                    (req, res, json, error)  in
                    if let json = self.handleAPIResponse(req, res: res, json_data: json, error: error){
                    }
```